# Why would StringLengthAttribute ErrorMessage behave differently in debug and release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a C# class with attribute like this to constrain the number of characters allowed

```
[StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be {2} to {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
public string TwoFactorCode { get; set; }
```

I am using this on an ASP.NET web site. The string length validation is run as part of a HTML form validation.

When I use this model in DEBUG mode the validation message output is as expected:

> TwoFactorCode must be 6 to 7 characters long.

When I run the same code in RELEASE mode the output becomes:

> 6 must be {2} to 7 characters long.

I can not find a logical explanation for this discrepancy. The documentation clearly states that the format string should be ok for the {0}, {1} and {2} params like this. And the .net C# source code ([StringLengthAttribute source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs)) supports that claim:

```
return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, errorMessage, name, this.MaximumLength, this.MinimumLength);
```

This is using .net 6.0.6 running on Windows 11 64bit. Tested on other Windows machines. Same results.

Comment: I don't see Maximum Length specified in the sample above - are you setting it somewhere else? I wonder if debug mode makes assumptions release  mode is not?

Comment: The first parameter of the StringLengthAttribute constructor is in fact the maximum length. That's 7 in the example given. It's not named specifically so it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: where is 100 value in your code? your range is 6 to 7 character.

Comment: I am very sorry about the confusion. I have edited the post to correctly show the numbers as displayed by the code when run.